# Медленная загрузка видео через HTML5 плеер

Tags: html, html5, видео

При просмотре видео через дефолтный HTML5 плеер, оно буферизируется очень медленно, но при прямой закачке видео как файл с сервера все происходит за считанные секунды. В чем может быть проблема медленной загрузки через плеер?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить `<link rel="prefetch" href="video">`для предварительной загрузки вашего видео. [Инфо W3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ)